# Strings on different screen size with different languages

Tags: android, android-screen

Is there a way that you can support different string values in different languages and screens (tablet or phone) in the same time?
For example something like this: values-de-sw600dp

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a new `Android Resource File` named *strings.xml* with those qualifiers?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Values of strings aren't necessarily related to different screen sizes, 
You can have one xml for each language(that have the text in each language), and one xml for each screen size (that saves the values of the size of text)

For example in a textview the property "text" point to the text source xml and the property "textSize" point to the text size xml

Documentation:

support different languages:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

support different screen sizes:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

It was somehow connected to this bug, because I was testing it on tablet emulator.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34360388/2489797

values-de-sw600dp now works!

Thanks for all your answers!